# SHIMANO STEPS(VOODOO ZOBOP 2019) ERROR E014 best solution?

Tags: shimano, electric-bike

customer dropped his voodoo zobop E7000 2019 bike, previously had E013, after huge firmware update E013 changed to E014 error code, apparently ECU not receiving signal from the battery...!? Would anyone know the best solution to get rid of this error code. Can it be done without replacing any parts?
Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search showed that E013 was a firmware error where Shimano suggests to upgrade the firmware (what you obviously did), E014 seems to be related to speed sensor mounting issues.

```
The speed sensor may have been installed in the wrong position.
```

See https://si.shimano.com/en/pdfs/um/79E0B/UM-79E0B-000-ENG.pdf page 50.

From your text, I assume you are a mechanic but as far as I understand, there could be two main problems

- The sensor has slipped on the spokes
- Wiring of the sensor connecting to the drive unit is damaged (I think the sensor is just a magnet, not sure if there is much that could go wrong, here).

Comment: Thank you DoNut!! There was a silly issue with this bike, r/axle wasnt all the way in... had to tighten it and the magnet moved closer to the sensor ;)) I switched the battery off, aligned magnet with sensor, tirn it back on and spinned the pedal for around 40sec and error disappeared.

Comment: @Virmantas No problem, at least it tells us that Shimano manuals are so good that even a non-e-biker/mechanic can fix things in an instant. Please check it as accepted answer, if you don't mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes E014 is the sensor issue, in my case rear axle wasnt all the way in, so I had to tighten it. After you tightened it and you are happy with sensor and magnet positioning align magnet with the sensor(make sure battery is of) then turn it on and spin the pedal for around 40sec-50sec.
ERROR WANISHED! happy days
Thanks for support guys!